# Conformal diffeomorphism of $\mathbb R^k$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, conformal-maps

Let $f$ be a conformal diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^k$, where $k\geq 2$, and its Euclidean metric. It follows from complex analysis and Liouville's theorem that $f$ can only be affine. Now, suppose $f:(\mathbb{R}^k,g_1)\to(\mathbb{R}^k,g_2)$ is a conformal diffeomorphism for some other smooth metric $g_1$ and $g_2$. Can we deduce a similar rigidity theorem as in the case of the Euclidean metric?

Comment: The question makes more sense if you assume $g_1=g_2$ (otherwise, take $f,g_1$ arbitrary and define $g_2=f_*g_1$.

Comment: For $g_1=g_2=g$. Take, for instance, $(\mathbf{R}^k,g)$ isometric to the real hyperbolic space. Then the isometry group is  essentially $\mathrm{SO}(k,1)$, and the latter doesn't embed into the $k$-dimensional affine group. Of course, things then depend on what you call "similar". For instance one can ask whether the conformal group is a finite-dimensional Lie group (for its natural topology).

Comment: I do not understand the question as it lacks sufficient precision. However, consider reading this paper with a solution of the Lichnerowicz conjecture: J. Ferrand, The action of conformal transformations on a Riemannian manifold. Math. Ann. 304 (1996), no. 2, 277–291.